# Is it possible to include static properties in a functional representation of a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With ES6, it is possible to represent a React Component as a function.

So, the following component

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    <div>Hi</div>
  }

}
```

could also be represented as such

```
const MyComponent = (props) => (
   <div>Hi</div>
)
```

My question is whether the functional representation also allows for static properties. So, I'm wondering whether it is possible to represent the following component somehow as a function as well:

```
class MyComponentWithStaticProperty extends React.Component {

  static myProperty = {'hello': 'world'}

  render() {
    <div>Hi</div>
  }

}
```

Comment: I mean in your constructor if you define `this.myProperty` as something then a `ref` of this component would be something like `this.refs.someComponent.myProperty`..... which is basically the same thing as a static property.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
const MyComponent = (props) => (
   <div>Hi</div>
)

MyComponent.myProperty = {'hello': 'world'};
```

Comment: to make this a complete answer you should use what I said in my comment on the question to cover the React class version of a static variable. Also adding text explaining why something is an answer is good too :)